# Select MySQL loop statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table :

`ID    ministry_id building_id        action_date             action_type
1        14         1653         2011-12-23 11:22:33               1
2        14         1653         2012-02-29 11:51:12               2
3        14         1653         2013-06-25 11:29:22               1
4        14         1653         2017-05-15 17:01:37               2`

When I select from this table, it returns this result:

```
ministry_id  building_id       add_date                   end_date
     14         1653        2011-12-23 11:22:33        2012-02-29 11:51:12
     14         1653        2013-06-25 11:29:22        2017-05-15 17:01:37
```

when action_type = 1 then action_date = add_date
when action_type = 2 then action_date = end_date

Comment: end date should be `2012-02-29 11:51:12` for the first record? right

Comment: could you be more clear? did not get what are you trying to achieve

Comment: it is not help, but there returned count

Comment: @Meqenaneri Vacharq - can the end_date before add_date ??

Comment: I want to select same action_date

Comment: please write query @Bernd Buffen

Comment: @Meqenaneri Vacharq - there is no way to find out which record is the next with action_id =2. Your order of the rows is not sure if there is no ORDER BY clause

Comment: I have auto_increment  id to equivalent orderby by action_date @Bernd Buffen

Comment: @Meqenaneri Vacharq - have have seen your answer to late. i write a new (better)  query in the next hour.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query. I only works if the end_date > add_date

```
SELECT 
    t1.ministry_id,
    t1.building_id,
    t1.action_date as add_date,
    MIN(t2.end_date) as end_date
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.action_date end_date, action_date
    FROM yourTable t
    WHERE t.action_type = 2 
    ) t2
    ON t1.action_date < t2.action_date
WHERE t1.action_type = 1
GROUP BY t1.action_date;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from yourTable;
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+
| ministry_id | building_id | action_date         | action_type |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+
|          14 |        1653 | 2011-12-23 11:22:33 |           1 |
|          14 |        1653 | 2012-02-29 11:51:12 |           2 |
|          14 |        1653 | 2013-06-25 11:29:22 |           1 |
|          14 |        1653 | 2017-05-15 17:01:37 |           2 |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT 
    -> t1.ministry_id,
    -> t1.building_id,
    -> t1.action_date as add_date,
    -> MIN(t2.end_date) as end_date
    -> FROM yourTable t1
    -> LEFT JOIN (
    -> SELECT t.action_date end_date, action_date
    -> FROM yourTable t
    -> WHERE t.action_type = 2 
    -> ) t2
    -> ON t1.action_date < t2.action_date
    -> WHERE t1.action_type = 1
    -> GROUP BY t1.action_date
    -> ;
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ministry_id | building_id | add_date            | end_date            |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          14 |        1653 | 2011-12-23 11:22:33 | 2012-02-29 11:51:12 |
|          14 |        1653 | 2013-06-25 11:29:22 | 2017-05-15 17:01:37 |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: this query will fail when sql_mode only_full_group_by is enabled on the server. -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a998ef/2 .. With other words you are misusing MySQL's GROUP BY feature which can lead into invalid results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a answer using id:

```
SELECT 
    t1.ministry_id,
    t1.building_id,
    t1.action_date as add_date,
    t2.action_date as end_date
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.id+1 = t2.id
WHERE t1.action_type = 1;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from yourTable;
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+
| id | ministry_id | building_id | action_date         | action_type |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+
|  1 |          14 |        1653 | 2011-12-23 11:22:33 |           1 |
|  2 |          14 |        1653 | 2012-02-29 11:51:12 |           2 |
|  3 |          14 |        1653 | 2013-06-25 11:29:22 |           1 |
|  4 |          14 |        1653 | 2017-05-15 17:01:37 |           2 |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT 
    -> t1.ministry_id,
    -> t1.building_id,
    -> t1.action_date as add_date,
    -> t2.action_date as end_date
    -> FROM yourTable t1
    -> LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    -> ON t1.id+1 = t2.id
    -> WHERE t1.action_type = 1;
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ministry_id | building_id | add_date            | end_date            |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          14 |        1653 | 2011-12-23 11:22:33 | 2012-02-29 11:51:12 |
|          14 |        1653 | 2013-06-25 11:29:22 | 2017-05-15 17:01:37 |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```